# Stop countdown on click

Tags: javascript, onclick, countdown

I want my countdown to stop on the click of a submit button, i searched in some pages,
but I didn't found anything.
Here is the code i want to stop on click

```
function countDown (count) {
  if (count > 0) {
   var d = document.getElementById("countDiv");
   d.innerHTML = count;
   setTimeout (function() { countDown(count-1); }, 1000);
   document.getElementById('tiempo').value = count;
  }
  else
   document.location = "timeover.php";
}
document.getElementById("palabra").focus();
countDown(5);
</script>
```

Comment: What does your code do? What you expect it to do instead? Where is the submit button? Where is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var stopped = false; 
function countDown (count) {
  if (count > 0) {
   var d = document.getElementById("countDiv");
   d.innerHTML = count;
   document.getElementById('tiempo').value = count;
   if (!stopped) { 
    setTimeout (function() { countDown(count-1); }, 1000);
   }
  }
  else
   document.location = "timeover.php";
}
document.getElementById("palabra").focus();
document.getElementById("mySubmitId").onclick = function () { 
  stopped = true;
};
countDown(5);
```

Comment: And where is a decreaser for `count` ; )?

Comment: @Teemu but countdown should be just stopped.

Comment: I thik it will, but seems that OP wants to show the remaining time (`count`) in an element. In your code this "display" stays at `4`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save reference to timeout (actually return value of timeout will be number) and use it to cancel timeout.

```
var timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
    // do something
}, 1000);

// clear timeout
window.clearTimeout(timeout);
```

You probably got the idea. By the way, you should probably look at `setInterval` method since it would be better in this situation. Interval will "tick" as long until you cancel it.